# What is the meaning of $\varphi (U \cap \mathcal M) =(\mathbb R^m \times \{0\})\cap V$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

In [this presentation](https://youtu.be/daqXfJdoXvo) an $m$-manifold is assumed to be embedded in $\mathbb R^k,$ and defined as a subset $\mathcal M \subseteq \mathbb R^k,$ such that for any point $c\in \mathcal M,$ there exist two sets $U,V\in \mathbb R^k$ with the point $c\in U$ and a diffeomorphism

$$\phi(U\cap \mathcal M) =(\mathbb R^m \times\{0\})\cap V.$$

I understand that $U$ is a neighborhood around $c,$ such as if the manifold is, for instance, some curved surface in 3D like a parabolic, $U$ would be like a curved disk as in the purple disk in:

[image]

?

Now $\mathbb R^m$ is the $XY$ plane (in gray), and the $x\{0\}$ means that the origin is included (? in the presentation it is mentioned as "cross").

Then what is $V$? Obviously everything there lives in $\mathbb R^k,$ which in this example is $\mathbb R^3$ in this case.

> But it is unclear to me if either $U$ or $V$ or both are disks (surfaces) or balls (volumes), and where they are located in space.

---

After the accepted answer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is:

> A subset $M\subset \Bbb{R}^k$ is an $m$-dimensional (embedded sub-)manifold of $\Bbb{R}^k$ of class $C^{\infty}$ if for any point $c\in M$ there exists an open set $U\subset\Bbb{R}^k$ which contains $c$, an open set $V\subset\Bbb{R}^k$ and a $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism $\varphi:U\to V$ such that $\varphi[M\cap U]=V\cap \left(\Bbb{R}^m\times\{0_{\Bbb{R}^{k-m}}\}\right)$.

Note that in this definition, the sets $U$ and $V$ are open in $\Bbb{R}^k$, meaning for every $p\in U$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that the open ball $\{x\in \Bbb{R}^k\,:\,\lVert x-p\rVert<\delta\}\subset U$ is completely contained in $U$.

So, in the picture, $U$ should not be thought of as a "curved disc". Rather you should think of it as an open ball; it is the **intersection** $M\cap U$ which is the "curved disc"; the purple region you shaded. To really understand this definition pictorially, you should imagine two copies of $\Bbb{R}^k$. The first copy is where your subset $M$ lives. The second copy you should think of as $\Bbb{R}^k=\Bbb{R}^m\times \Bbb{R}^{k-m}$; it is in this second copy where the open set $V$ lives, and the intersection of $V$ with the "flat plane" $\Bbb{R}^m\times\{0_{\Bbb{R}^{k-m}}\}$ should correspond (via the diffeomorphism $\varphi$)to $M\cap U$.

Let me try to explain in words what the definition is saying. It says that given any point $c$ of your subset $M$, if you look at a nearby portion of $M$ (i.e $M\cap U$) then we can always "flatten it out" to look like a piece of $\Bbb{R}^m$ (i.e find a diffeomorphism such that $\phi[M\cap U]=V\cap (\Bbb{R}^m\times \{0_{\Bbb{R}^{k-m}}\})$). The [following picture](https://images.app.goo.gl/Lbt6AT2MRpUF1PEPA) might help with intuition.

Comment: Thank you! Clear as light!

Comment: I am re-reading it to make sure I understand the details before I accept. What is $\Bbb{R}^m\times \{0_{\Bbb{R}^{k-m}}\}$ in words?

Comment: @Mathtourist Note that $\Bbb{R}^k$ is equal (strictly speaking isomorphic to) the set $\Bbb{R}^m\times \Bbb{R}^{k-m}$. So, $\Bbb{R}^m\times\{0\}$ refers to the set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^{k-m}\,:\,\,\, y=0\}$. Another way of saying it is it is the set $\{(x_1,\dots, x_k)\in\Bbb{R}^k\,:\, x_{m+1}=\dots = x_k=0\}$. (kind of like the $x,y$ plane when thought of as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$).

Comment: If you have the patience... "m -dimensional (embedded sub-)manifold" means that it is a "sub" because the big guy is actually $\mathbb R^k$?

Comment: @Mathtourist yes exactly. Also, the "embedded" is just another technical term referring to these nice regularity conditions we have imposed. One could also define a manifold $M$ abstractly, and then talk about "an embedded submanifold of $M$".

Comment: Yes, I have been fascinated for a while with the Nash embedding theorem. I like to read things I don't understand.